# What variables will be sent to an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with a javascript mini-library called Reqwest. It's suppose to do ajax-requests, but in internet explorer it throws the error. `Peer dependency xhr2 required! Please npm install xhr2'`. Xhr2 is a library is suppose to be used with node.js I run the code in the frontend.

I'm trying to understand what this code does, how it get's executed and where the variables come from. My best bet right now is that for some reason `context.hasOwnProperty('window')` is false and that assumes that the code is running server side. But I have no idea why.

```
!function (name, context, definition) {
  if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) module.exports = definition()
  else if (typeof define == 'function' && define.amd) define(definition)
  else context[name] = definition()
}('reqwest', this, function () {

  var context = this

  if (context.hasOwnProperty('window')) {
    var doc = document
      , byTag = 'getElementsByTagName'
      , head = doc[byTag]('head')[0]
  } else {
    var XHR2
    try {
      XHR2 = require('xhr2')
    } catch (ex) {
      throw new Error('Peer dependency `xhr2` required! Please npm install xhr2')
    }
  }
...
}
```

Comment: *Privacy* is the word

Comment: `"reqwest"`? Normally, I'd fix typo's, but this one's in the code... Or is that intentional?

Comment: reqwest is a js-library for ajax requests.

Comment: Ah, I see. Silly name ;-)

Comment: the error says that you needs `xhr2`. Probably, that's not clear enough ?

Comment: @KarelG xhr2 is a npm-module, the code checks if it's running in a browser. And it believes it doesn't even though it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all.

```
!function(){}();
```

It's a shortcut of

```
( function() {} )();
```

That simply execute the anonymous function `function() {}` immediately

So for example,

```
!function(arg1){ console.log(arg1); }("argument1");
```

Will print `argument1`.

Now:

```
!function(name,context, definition)
```

`name`, `context` and `definition` are respectively `"reqwest"`, `this` and anonymous function declared

In a browser, the object `this` is the `Window` Object, but in Node.js it's the equivalent of module.exports object (empty object if not filled by any other module)

Now, inside the anonymous function

```
(typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports)
```

Check if we are in a Node.js environment, that the object `module` and `module.exports` are always defined.

```
(typeof define == 'function' && define.amd)
```

Check if we have requireJs available (in a browser env).

In the first case it exports the module executing the function passed as argument (that will returns an object or function). It's like Node.js works.

In the second case execute the function define, like requireJs works.

In the last case, put the module (as return of function) in the context object (Window probably).

Inside the function we have this:

```
if (context.hasOwnProperty('window')) {
```

This check if we're in browser environemnt (the Object window has the property window). 
If we're in a browser, we have some native functions (like XMLHttpRequest), but in Node.js we have to load as external library (like xhr2). Then

```
XHR2 = require('xhr2')
```

and so on... :)